# REST and Email Addresses in the URI

Tags: wcf, email, rest, character-encoding

I am using WCF / .NET 4.0 / IIS7.5 / Sever 2008

I want to do this:

http://localhost/users/email/bill@microsoft.com

But, it shows up on the server like this:

"bill"

The "@microsoft" gets removed.

I understand that the at symbol is a special case. 
Is there a graceful way to do this? Can I instruct
my WebGet method that this method is going to take
a special symbol and please encode it?

```
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/email/{email}")]
    [WebDispatchFormatter]
    [OperationContract]
    UserDto GetUserByEmail(string email);
```

How do I manipulate email addresses using WCF REST?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use special characters in a URI, you have to URI Encode them and then decode on the service side. Since this is .NET, you can utilize the encode/decode bits for URL encoding.

Comment: how do I encode the email address if it is being issued as a CURL string from an iPhone applicaton? Do I need to tell the client-side app developer to encode the email string?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to escape the @ sign. Try `http://localhost/users/email/bill%40microsoft.com`

Comment: I think I may have selected "answer" too soon. It still snips off the "%40microsoft.com" and just returns bill... hmmm